# How do I specify a custom field for uid in an omniauth strategy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I'm building an omniauth strategy to work with the Suunto API. The request to their `token_url` returns a response that includes a `user` key/value:

```
{
  "access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "refresh_token":"REFRESH_TOKEN",
  "expires_in":86399,
  "scope":"workout",
  "ukv":"1",
  "uk":"SOME_VALUE",
  "user":"UID",
  "jti":"SOME_VALUE"
}
```

This is meant to be used as the `uid` value.

Based on [the Declarative Configuration docs](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Strategy-Contribution-Guide#declarative-configuration) I tried this, with no luck:

```rb
option :fields, [:user]
option :uid_field, :user
```

This doesn't work because the field isn't present in the request, it's in the `token_url` response:

```rb
uid do
  request.params[options.uid_field.to_s]
end
```

[The Defining the Callback Phase docs](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Strategy-Contribution-Guide#defining-the-callback-phase) has a note about `credentials`, but there's no usage example.

What should I add/edit in my strategy that will tell it to set the `uid` value to the `user` that's returned from the token request's response?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! I figured it out. This goes into the strategy:

```rb
uid { raw_info["user"] }

def raw_info
  @raw_info ||= access_token
end
```

At that point in `raw_info`, `access_token` is the hash that I included in the opening of my question.